# Removed/Re-Added file, now I get Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app, I removed then re-added a class. The target membership for the .m file is checked and it appears under Build Phases->Compile Sources. "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No", and the "Valid Architectures" are "arm64 armv7 armv7s". I also tried clearing out the DerivedData folder. What other ways are there to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

ios sdk 9.3

into your build setting of app.xcodeproj valid architecture: armv7 armv7s Build Active architecture : No

Clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty crazy stuff. Figured it out. Turns out the specific class I added calls some C++ functions, so I needed to change its file type to Objective-C++ in the Identity Inspector.